# Subscribers Group User meta delete

Tags: user-meta

We offer articles contribution form our user we create articles on behalf the subscribers as result of the we as a website team about 40 account in 4 groups and 240k user as subscribers causing user meta table to be around 2m and 800k record wich causing some problems who can i remove all user meta for 240 subscribers from meta user and keep the account it self in user table even as non functional account no one will use it

- I need A way to delete any meta entry from meta table for subscribers
  group

i tried some plugins to see i i can remove this and  i try to delete the user meta using sql but i could not because each user has about 15 entry in table

Thanks

Comment: May you please elaborate your question? I'm not understanding what you're looking to do.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan i update the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not getting your question in order for me to help you. May you please add more details to your question? Also what have you done to try to solve this yourself?